# Can I retrieve the interface type within an interface method?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

How can I determine the underlying interface from which the method `DoSomething()` is called? Additional question: Can I already determine the underlying interface in the MyClass constructor? I assume not as it is not known at instantiation time, correct?

**Edit:** I am not looking for explicit interface implementations but a different way to determine the underlying interface.

```
public interface ITest
{
    void DoSomething();
    //....more methods
}

public interface IDecoy
{
    void DoSomething();
    //...more methods
}

public class MyClass : ITest, IDecoy
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Question: How can I determine the underlying interface that called this method?
        //at one time it is ITest, at another IDecoy. How can I figure out which one at each time?
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        ITest myClassInstance1 = new MyClass();
        IDecoy myClassInstance2 = new MyClass();

        myClassInstance1.DoSomething();
        myClassInstance2.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not just declare the `DoSomething` method explicitly so that you know which interface you are implementing?  Think `void IDecoy.DoSomething()` and `void ITest.DoSomething()`.

Comment: Why don`t you explicitly implement the interfaces ? Like: `public void ITest.DoSomething() {}` and `public void IDecoy.DoSomething() {}`

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work because I am actually not dealing with an interface Method but class decorating attributes. My question really pertains to being able **anywhere** within the class constructor or class methods which underlying interface it is

Comment: @MattWolf than modify, or add new question with attributes, because those are different questions I guess

Comment: Sorry I should have not said "its not working". I can get it to work as suggested through explicit interface implementation. But I wonder whether there is a different way without going through explicit interface implementations. Will edit to specify that explicit interface implementation is not what I am looking for. Sorry

Comment: If the same method maps to two distinct interfaces, there is no way for you to determine inside the method through which interface the call was made. The answer by @ArsenMkrt is the only way, by basically making two separate methods so that you know explicitly which interface each method maps to.

Comment: @MattWolf I have managed to find a solution to the question that does not require using explicit declarations - see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class MyClass : ITest, IDecoy
{
    void ITest.DoSomething()
    {
        //called with ITest 
    }
    void IDecoy.DoSomething()
    {
        //called with IDecoy 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping that there is a different way to know but this seems to be the only way.

Comment: I don't think you can find another way of doing this, you can describe your question with attributes in a new post, may be it will be another solution to that question

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I guess if there is no other way here then neither will there be withe Attribute issue. I use MEF and decorated my plugin with 2 custom Attributes. I wanted to have the right attribute (through access to the meta data one of which is the interface type) assigned to the custom attribute property upon calling either the constructor (which for sure does not work) or, as described here, through a method. As long as I know the interface type as you suggested I can use `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(...)` and select the matching attribute to assign.

Comment: ...of course the probably easier way is to use the attribute instance outside and just pass it in when MEF imports the plugin and creates and instance either somehow through the constructor or an additional method.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite intriguing, and so I set out to see whether it was possible to find a way of identifying which interface was used without the solution already suggested.

The solution I am using essentially finds the metadata token of the method that was called in the IL code of the caller and looks this up against the metadata token of the `DoSomething` method from each interface:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    StackFrame CallerFrame;
    StackTrace CallStack;
    int CodeOffset;
    MethodBody MethodBody;
    int MethodToken;
    int TokenIDecoy;
    int TokenITest;

    // Get the metadata tokens for both interface methods
    TokenIDecoy = Type.GetType("Proto.SO18203446.IDecoy").GetMethod("DoSomething").MetadataToken;
    TokenITest = Type.GetType("Proto.SO18203446.ITest").GetMethod("DoSomething").MetadataToken;

    // Get the caller
    CallStack = new StackTrace();
    CallerFrame = CallStack.GetFrame(1);

    // Get the metadata token called by the IL
    CodeOffset = CallerFrame.GetILOffset();
    MethodBody = CallerFrame.GetMethod().GetMethodBody();
    MethodToken = BitConverter.ToInt32(MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray(), CodeOffset - 4);

    // Check to see which interface was used
    if (MethodToken == TokenIDecoy)
        Console.WriteLine("IDecoy was called");
    else if (MethodToken == TokenITest)
        Console.WriteLine("ITest was called");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Not sure what happened here");
}
```

Remember to change the `GetType` call parameter to be your own namespace (so mine is `Proto.SO18203446` but yours is very likely to be somehting else).

The steps of the process are simple:

- Lookup the metadata tokens for each interface `DoSomething` method
- Find the calling frame (the one that makes the call to `DoSomething`)
- Lookup the IL offset of the call to the `DoSomething` method and extract the metadata token for it
- Compare the called metadata token to the token for each `DoSomething` in the interfaces

I would like to add that I am not recommending or endorsing this code - it is more to prove that it is possible to achieve your aim from an academic perspective.

Comment: Very interesting. I will look deeper into it as I came across many question marks at first sight (due to relative unfamiliarity with IL). It looks like that I need to provide information about the potential interfaces, correct?

Comment: @MattWolf Supplying the fully qualified type name is all that will be necessary - so `Namespace.Type` in the call to `GetType`.